# How to add column to data frame after subsetting it with plyr?

Tags: r

Say I wanted to work with hospital Medicare data showing procedure prices by hospital and by county and my data frame was called df with columns price, procedure and county. If I wanted to find the minimum and maximum prices for each procedure by county, I could so something like

```
library(plyr)
mostexpensive <- ddply(df,c('county','procedure'),function(x)x[which(x$price==max(x$price)),])
```

to get a table showing the hospitals with the most expensive procedures in each county. I can then see how many times each hospital is listed with

```
summary(mostexpensive$hospital)
```

For the final step I want to add a column to the original df dataframe that says TRUE if the row is most expensive and FALSE otherwise but I can't figure out how to get a logical vector from a plyr function. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting reproducible code would be useful. Try this anyway,

For the summary

```
pricey <- ddply(df, c('county','procedure'), summarise, most = max(price), less=min(price))
```

and for the logical indexing

```
testing <- ddply(df, c('county','procedure'), mutate, expensive = price == max(price))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, works perfectly, and sorry not to have full reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

It will be more easier to get an answer with a reproductible example. You should think about it, next time you as for help in SO.

That being said, you can use the `transform` function to add a new column to your existing data.

The first step is to create a toy data set.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
    county = sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 20, replace = TRUE),
    procedure = sample(c(1, 2), size = 20, replace = TRUE),
    price = rpois(20, 10)
)

str(df)
## 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ county   : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 3 2 3 3 1 2 3 2 2 ...
##  $ procedure: num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
##  $ price    : int  6 8 6 8 4 6 6 8 5 12 ...
```

Now we can use `plyr` and the `transform` function

```
require(plyr)
expensive <- ddply(df, .(county, procedure),
                   transform, ismax = price == max(price))


expensive
##    county procedure price ismax
## 1       A         1     9 FALSE
## 2       A         1     7 FALSE
## 3       A         1    12  TRUE
## 4       A         2     6 FALSE
## 5       A         2     6 FALSE
## 6       A         2     8  TRUE
## 7       B         1     5 FALSE
## 8       B         1    12  TRUE
## 9       B         2     6 FALSE
## 10      B         2     6 FALSE
## 11      B         2    12  TRUE
## 12      B         2    11 FALSE
## 13      C         1     9  TRUE
## 14      C         1     9  TRUE
## 15      C         2     8 FALSE
## 16      C         2     8 FALSE
## 17      C         2     4 FALSE
## 18      C         2     8 FALSE
## 19      C         2    12  TRUE
## 20      C         2    12  TRUE
```